# Un-able to check status of a check box using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python, and I am trying to write a script to verify a check-box has been checked/enabled. My problem is that I am not able to read the correct value after the check box has been checked/selected or un-checked/un-selected.

I was able to locate the check box, select/enable it, then click "apply" to confirm the change. But when I tried to verify the check box's status, I could not get the correct value.
If I used `.is_enabled()`, the read value would always be "True" no matter what the check box has been selected/enabled or not.
And If I used `.is_selected()`, the value would always be "False".

Please help. Below is my code:

```
Locate_Checkbox = Browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div')

Ranging = Locate_Checkbox.is_selected() 

print(Ranging)
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I just added a more detailed screen shoot of the html at this link https://www.flickr.com/photos/196113483@N08/shares/5hdg8c

Answer (score 0):

because it is div not input with type checkbox, so is_selected is not feasible for your case. you can try as the following: Locate_Checkbox = Browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div').getAttribute("class"); based on class attribute to know whether the div is checked or not, seems when checked, the class is "at-checkbox at-checked", it not check, suppose it is "at-checkbox", you can try to see that –

Comment: Can you share the html code ?

Comment: @justin, explain how your answer solves the OP's problem and add some relevant context to it.

Comment: because the purpose is to find the checkbox property, but from xpath '//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div', it is div, not input with type 'checkbox', so I think the xpath should be similar as  '//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]'.  if he can share the html code, then can give detail xpath

Comment: Add this as part of answer and not as comment, your answer looks similar to code in the OP's post.

Comment: you can ask for HTML in the comments below the problem statement.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but still have the same issue.

Comment: Hi all, here is the html code which I copied via Inspect, then Edit as HTML.

Comment: <div class="at-checkbox-parent ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="top: 212px; left: 745px;"><div class="at-checkbox at-checked"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check at-checkmark ng-star-inserted"></i><!--bindings={

  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"

}--></div></div>

Comment: because it is div not input with type checkbox, so is_selected is not feasible for your case. you can try as the following:     Locate_Checkbox = Browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div').getAttribute("class");  based on class attribute to know whether the div is checked or not,  seems when checked, the class is "at-checkbox at-checked", it not check, suppose it is "at-checkbox", you can try to see that

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for helping me out on this question.

Answer (score 0):

[`is_enabled()`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/#is-enabled) is used to check whether element is connected and enable to perform the operation in the current context of the page. And NOT to check whether it is selected or not.

[`is_selected()`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/#is-selected) is used to check whether the element is selected or not. This method is used on checkboxes, input boxes, radio buttons.

In your case you should rely on the `is_selected()` However if you use this function with `find_element()` it will never reach to the is_selected() method if in case of you have exception in finding the element. Probably that is what is happening in your case. To solve this problem you will have to use `find_element**s**()` variant.
This will return you empty list incase of exception in finding element. for example.

```
locate_Checkbox = Browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div')

if len(locate_Checkbox) > 0:
    Ranging = locate_Checkbox[0].is_selected() 

print(Ranging)
```

Comment: Hi Dev, I tried your suggestion, and got the following error:

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Comment: you did not notice the extra 's' in the `find_elements()` function name, it will return you list and not a Webelement.

Comment: Hi Dev, I tried your suggestion with find_elements, and ran into a different error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. Any suggestions?

Comment: This time you must have missed the `len()` to use for list. Also if you don't know the basics go to python documentation. The answer pretty much addresses the problem you posted, either accept the answer and post new question with new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all especially Justin for helping me on this question. I really appreciate it.

I tried the below command and it works perfectly.

Locate_Checkbox = Browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="at-contain"]/sd-canvas-home/div/span/div[3]/sd-canvas/div/div/at-checkbox[11]/div/div').get_attribute("class")

Once again, thank you all.